# how to always store application to sdcard/external storage

Tags: android, file, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am making one android app, for which I want to store the downloaded images to sdcard or external storage. The problem I am facing is that on some phone the images are being stored on sdcard whereas in some phones it is being stored in internal memory, specifically in samsung devices like Galaxy S4. Please see the attached images for the file path in S4.

```
File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + "/TestApp/");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/TestApp/" + secret + ".jpg");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Wallpaper saved sucessfully \n"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .toString() + "/TestApp/" + secret
                            + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

[image: storage on s4]

Comment: That's because on devices such as the Nexus 7 and the Samsung Galaxy S4 Google Edition, they don't have external cards.  They have emulated ones.  So the system is designed to store it in a fake external location.

Comment: @JaySnayder: Not really. "External" != "removable".

Comment: In short, no. You can't do this in any API-supported way.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, it doesn't mean removable, but it does mean in another location other than the internal application location.  You aren't writing to your app location there to internal.  You are writing to external.

Comment: Does that mean, there's no problem with the code?

Comment: @android_newbie Yes, and of course CommonsWare explained it nice and clean below with additional aide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am making one android app, for which I want to store the downloaded images to sdcard or external storage.

The Android SDK offers access to external storage. Whether this is "sdcard" or something else is up to the device manufacturer.

> The problem I am facing is that on some phone the images are being stored on sdcard whereas in some phones it is being stored in internal memory, specifically in samsung devices like Galaxy S4.

This code stores the images on external storage. It is not storing them on internal storage. Whether external storage is removable or not is up to the device manufacturer.

You may wish to consider reading [the documentation about external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

You should also:

- Not use string concatenation to create `File` objects. Use the proper `File` constructor.
- Store your data somewhere better than in a hardcoded `TestApp` directory off the root of external storage, such as `getExternalFilesDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()`. Your approach has been considered poor form for years, as it clutters up the user's external storage.
- Use a more-focused approach for updating `MediaStore`, such as using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`, rather than sending out an operating system broadcast, as if you were the operating system.
- Be sure to do all of this work on a background thread (it is unclear whether you are or are not from the code snipppet).

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. Its my very early days with android developments. I will keep in mind the things that you have pointed out